Serve multiple devices with `nbd-server -C specific-config`
I'm running the nbd-server package on Debian.
I'm trying to add and remove individual served nbd files without restarting the nbd-server (as discussed in this question).

I can specify a specific config file with nbd-server -C specificconfig.
I can use this to start multiple nbd-server sessions, each with its own PID.
Problem: When I try to connect to the second server I start, I get this output on the client:

Negotiation: ..Error: Unknown error returned by server. Server said: Export unknown
Exiting.


How can I use this to serve multiple nbd files?
nbd-server -C config1
nbd-server -C config2 # This one fails when connecting with nbd-client -N ... on the client


Currently I could not run different exports on different ports , or multiple nbd servers on different port , or connect to single server with multiple clients (read-only file).
Probably this will work :
https://www.libguestfs.org/nbdkit-multi-conn-filter.1.html
Edit :
This definitely works :
nbdkit 1.38.2
nbdkit -r myfile.ext  (on server side) 
nbd-client <ip> <port> /dev/nbd<X>   (on client side) 

Tested with multiple clients ... Sha256sum'med the file and it works ...

Could you please quote from that so that the most essential part we can see here without visiting that page? If we must visit the link to get the important content for a brief answer, it is link-only answer.

I have added details how to use it I have built from aur in archlinux tedted with mulitple VM s and bare-metal machines... I hope it will be useful.

Thank you! I greatly appreciate finally having an answer. I will review it when I have time.
